# java heap space error with connect rt.jar

Tags: android

I wanna generate an application which it will collaborate with Matlab M file. I found that a Matlab developed a packet for java. The packet is created a Java class from Matlab M file. This packet is generated a special jar file (this jar file needs a Javabuilder.jar and it is included in Matlab deployed packet) and it works very well on java. I wanna add Matlab generated jar file (which I call my.jar) to my Android project. I added my.jar and Javabuilder.jar on my project and I founded that Javabuilder.jar file needs java rt.jar. I attached rt.jar on the project too and I faced a java heap space error. I found below solution to solve java heap space error but none of them could not solve my problem.

- changed -Xms40m and -Xmx512m values which there are available in Eclips.ini, to Xms256m and Xmx1024m
- I run my Emulator with partision-size of 100m
- I added android:largeHeap="true" command 
  Who has a new suggestion? 
  I would appreciate if someone help me
  Regardes 
  Bahram

Comment: rt.jar is J2SE runtime library. Android has it's own, which contains a subset of J2SE plus Android extensions. You cannot plug J2SE rt.jar into Android because it will conflict with Android's core library.

Comment: share you .ini file for eclipse

Comment: mr Hussain Akhtar Wahid
do you know which library of android plays the same rule of rt.jar file?

Comment: mr Hussain Akhtar Wahid

do you know which library of android plays the same rule of rt.jar file? maybe I can change some part of Matlab deployed file and use it on android :( 
I really need to run Matlab M file on android and Matlab has not deployed a packet for Android yet. I was thinking that I can use java deployed class on Android but i have faced many problem.
do you have any idea how I can use Matlab M file in Android?